# Retrieve Object value from AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask

i am create asynctask, retreive string data:

```
View.OnClickListener btnClk = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (btnGetData.getId() == ((Button) v).getId()) {

            Object obj = new FetchTask(Main.this).execute((Integer) null);
        }
    }
};
```

my task:

```
public class FetchTask extends AsyncTask<Object, Object, Object> {

    private Context ctx;
    private String xml;

    public FetchTask(Context context) {
        ctx = context;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        DialogDownload_Ring = ProgressDialog.show(Main.this, "Download...",
                "Fetching XML data...");
        DialogDownload_Ring.setCancelable(true);
        DialogDownload_Ring.setOnCancelListener(new OnCancelListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                cancel(true);
            }
        });
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCancelled() {

        super.onCancelled();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Object result) {

        if (result instanceof Exception) {
            DialogDownload_Ring.setMessage("Download failed!");

        } else {
            DialogDownload_Ring.setMessage("Succesfully Downloaded!");
        }
        DialogDownload_Ring.dismiss();
        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }

    @Override
    protected Object doInBackground(Object... params) {

        try {
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(URL_Local);

            HttpResponse httpResponce = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponce.getEntity();
            xml = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);
            return xml;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return e;
        }
    }
}
```

How to retreive xml data from Object obj? obj.toString() not working. Else i create asynctask string properties (extends AsyncTask String, String, String) it's working but progressbar started after retreive xml data, i also do not understand. Help me please.
P.S. Sorry my English not good..

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables Thanks for the info. I didn't think there was a  `clogging` issue. But by all typos, you mean in someone's question as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to get a result back in the main ui thread after `doInBackground` execution complete then you will need to execute AsyncTask by calling [AsyncTask.get()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#get%28%29) method but this will freeze the UI thread until doInBackground execution is complete. You will need to call `AsyncTask.get()` inside a Thread to avoid a UI freeze. Start `AsyncTask` as to get the result back in the UI Thread:

```
Object obj = new FetchTask(Main.this).execute((Integer) null).get();
```

A Second way is start AsyncTask without calling `AsyncTask.get` method and receive the result in `onPostExecute` method when `doInBackground` execution is complete.
start AsyncTask as on button click:

```
new FetchTask(Main.this).execute((Integer) null);
```

get result in `onPostExecute` as :

```
 @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Object result) {

           // extract xml from result 

        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }
```

Comment: @xck : u can use `obj.toString()` to get String from Object and then convert it to xml document . if u have any issue then change AsyncTask return type to String

Comment: @xck : chnage your AsyncTask as http://pastebin.com/LQT3XZ51 to return string from  doInBackground

Comment: Thanks, how retreive PostExecute data (String obj=result; //<< get here xml ) from external procedure?

Comment: @xck : you will need to move your all part which u want to update using xml inside onPostExecute and use static getting / setting with collections like ArrayList,Maps.. for storing or getting data outside  AsyncTask

Comment: I create "public static String dataFromFetch" and use in PostExcute Main.dataFromFetch = result... This option may be right?

Comment: @xck : yes this is right but u will get data in `Main.dataFromFetch` variable when  AsyncTask execution complete

Comment: @xck : hi, if this answer help u in solving ur current issue then mark it as answer.Thanks

Comment: @xck : if u like it or this answer help u in solving issue then you   accept it by clicking on "RIGHT SIGN" on upper corner.

Comment: Yes i clicked.. Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 0):

ASyncTask doesn't work like this:

```
Object obj = new FetchTask(Main.this).execute((Integer) null);
```

The execute method returns immediately and the task continues on the background.

ASyncTask is asynchronous, so that's why it has `onPostExecute` method to do stuff when it finishes. Put code to deal with returned item (xml) into `onPostExecute` before or after you dismiss dialog.