# android use the class object returned from async

Tags: java, android, asynchronous

```
private class QueryResult {
    List<String> name = new ArrayList<>();
    List<String> location = new ArrayList<>();
    List<String> type = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Calendar> end = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Calendar> start = new ArrayList<>();
    public QueryResult( List<String> name,List<String> location,List<String> type, List<Calendar> end, List<Calendar> start ) {
        this.name=name;
        this.location=location;
        this.type=type;
        this.end=end;
        this.start=start;
    }
```

I want to return 5 arraylists so i return

```
return new QueryResult(namee,locationn,typee,end,strt);
```

this queryresult class is private in async class.

I call this async in mainactivity, in oncreate. But i cant use that arraylists. Because it is private class and i can only put to like this

```
 Object obj= new RetrieveFeedTask().execute().get();
```

but i cant do anything with that obj. Should i make class public to use that arrays? what is solution? or should i return multiple different type of arrays 
with different method? i couldnot find. i cant retrieve those arrays

i am returning those arrays inside doinbackground but i dont think which method of async is important now.

[Retrieve Object value from AsyncTask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14807028/retrieve-object-value-from-asynctask)

this did not work because it gives error when write mainactivity or main.

i made public class and with getter i got but still not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, never call AsyncTask.execute.get.  Doing so removes the entire reason and advantage of using an AsyncTask, and is wrong 99.9% of the time.  It will freeze your phone, making it unresponsive.

Secondly, never use it in onCreate. onCreate has a watchdog timer, you can trip the timer and your app will be terminated.

The correct way to use an AsyncTask is to put all the code that requires the result of the task in the onPostExecute function (or a function called from there).  Do not put it after calling execute, and do not call get to get the result.  Then only call AsyncTask.execute().

There are 1 or two exceptions to this, but if you don't know enough to answer this question for yourself then you aren't at a point where you can correctly determine those exceptions-  so just don't do it.

Comment: AsyncTask.execute(); and where to get object?

Comment: You don't.  The value will be passed to onPostExecute of your AsyncTask, where you should put all the logic you'd need the result for.  If your activity can't do anything without that logic, put up a loading page or spinner until you get it.

Comment: i am taking event names location there, then in main i take user location. then i will find the nearest locations with another function, maybe computedistance. so you say, do all this inside postexecute? but The AsyncTask will live as long as doInBackground lives so i will do all those jobs inside backinground but at last, i need to return again nearest location names addresses.i cant put to screen from there?

Comment: onPostExecute runs on the UI thread, so you can update the UI from there.  That's the main advantage to using an AsyncTask over just creating a Thread.

Comment: so in pre,calculate user location, on inbackground get addesses and calculate nearest and at post, post to ui. Or do you suggest all to do in background except posting to ui?

Comment: Generally you use onPreExecute to setup the UI to show that you're processing if you need to (for example to put up a loading page or spinner), doInBackground to do all your calculations, and onPostExecute to update the UI when done.